# How to store all checkbox id and values in a 2D array and and to php pages using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an input `type=checkbox` that contains `id` from `1-10`. I need to select some check boxes and when I click on a particular click event I need to store all checkboxes values `(1-0/ checked-not checked)` and `id`s in 2d array and send to php page using ajax.

```
<input type="checkbox" id='1' name="ppackages" class="success">
```

```js
var popularpackages = [];

$("input:checkbox").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
      popularpackages.push($this.attr("id"));
});

alert(popularpackages);
```

The output is `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`
But I need as `(id,checked/not checked)`
`(1,1),(2,0),.....(10,0)`

Comment: Do you mean you need `[{"id1":"1"},{"id2":"0"},{"id3":"0"},...]` format or do you need a flat object like `{1:0,2:1,...}`? What exactly is the problem with @RoryMcCrossan suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `map()` to build the array, then return the `id` and `checked` properties as a sub array, like this:

```js
var popularpackages = $("input:checkbox").map(function() {
  return [[parseInt(this.id, 10), this.checked ? 1 : 0]];
}).get();

console.log(popularpackages);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="ppackages" class="success" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="ppackages" class="success" />
<input type="checkbox" id="3" name="ppackages" class="success" />
<input type="checkbox" id="4" name="ppackages" class="success" />
<input type="checkbox" id="5" name="ppackages" class="success" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="6" name="ppackages" class="success" />
<input type="checkbox" id="7" name="ppackages" class="success" />
<input type="checkbox" id="8" name="ppackages" class="success" />
<input type="checkbox" id="9" name="ppackages" class="success" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" id="10" name="ppackages" class="success" />
```

You can then send the `popularpackages` array to your PHP logic using `$.ajax`, or any of jQuery's other AJAX methods, as you normally would.

Comment: What is 10 in this.id, 10 ?

Comment: That's the radix: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Syntax

Comment: Okay, thats fine. the output is correct. I can create the object of popularpackages and send the same object to php page using ajax. 
as   var objdata     = new FormData();   objdata.append("popularpackages ",popularpackages );

Comment: I meant to say I also need to use multiple update query in php to update the id with values

Comment: I'd ask a separate question about that, as it concerns handling the request in PHP. This question is about creating the array to be sent through JS.

Comment: In short, you can simply do a `json_decode($_POST['popularpackages], true)` and then work with the resulting `php array`

Comment: Yes. It builds a 2D array, as your question specfies

Comment: OKay, sorry... Please have a look on this too
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54038849/how-to-use-multiple-update-query-using-prepare-statements-in-php-for-storing-the/54039026?noredirect=1#comment94913385_54039026

Comment: I'd love to help with that, but I'm not a PHP dev