# How to use multiple update query using prepare statements in PHP for storing the values from an arrray?

Tags: php, sql, ajax

How to use update query for multiple values in a single shot with prepare statement in a single shot. I have an array with name $popularpackages and i want to use prepare statement to update table records in a single shot

```
  $packageid= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['packageid']);
  $maxcount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['loop']);
  for($loop = 0; $loop < $maxcount; $loop++){
           $packageid = $packageid[$loop];
   }
 $sql = $conn->prepare("update tbl_packagedetails set popularpackages =? where packageid =?;");
 $sql->bind_param("ii",popularpackages, $packageid);
 $sql->execute();
```

$popularpackages contains (id, value) as (1,0),(2,0),(3,1),....(10,0)

Comment: short answer you can't. You have to do it in a loop

Comment: You can do it using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql, but I would stick with a loop as it's more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop it. But you should begin transaction before, run the loop and executing and only when the loop finishes you should commit. This way you will only have one transaction instead of multiple which is what I think you want to achieve.

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();

<loop while executing>

$dbh->commit();
```

Comment: Not really... is just as if you run multiple updates from the console in one transaction. You can benchmark it.

Comment: can you just help me with code so that i can understand the concept

Comment: This answer covers what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106963/php-prepared-statements-and-transactions-in-a-loop

Comment: OKay, thats fine but how to read $packageid values that contains id and value.